# Nextjs: How to use ContextAPI with multiple values all of which need to be updated from child components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-context

I store three values in the context provider wrapper function. I need to update the context states in the login and logout components, and use them in navbar and in any other places.

```
const AppContext = createContext();

const AppContextProvider = (props) => {
    const loggedIn = Cookies.get('isLoggedIn') ? true : false;
    const [ isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn ] = useState(isLoggedIn);
    const [ userID, setUserID ] = useState('');
    const [ email, setEmail ] = useState('');

    return (
        <AppContext.Provider value={[isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn, userID, setUserID, email, setEmail ]}>
            {props.children}
        </AppContext.Provider>
    );
}

export { AppContext, AppContextProvider };
```

In the `_app.js` it's this:

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <>
      <AppContextProvider>
        <NavBar />
        <Component {...pageProps} />
        <Footer />
      </AppContextProvider>
    </>
  );
}
```

But now, the trouble is, I can't understand how to update these context states. This is my use case in login component:

```
const [ isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn, userID, setUserID, email, setEmail ] = useContext(AppContext);
const handleSubmit = async() => {
    const url = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL + 'auth/login/';
    const data = { "email": email, "password": password };
    try {
        const resp = await axios.post(url, data);
        const obj = await resp.data;
        Cookies.set('isLoggedIn', true, { secure: true }, { sameSite: 'lax' });
        setIsLoggedIn(true);
        setUserID(obj.uid);
        setEmail(obj.email);
    } catch (err) {...};
```

This way, it didn't work. I could not get the context values in other components. How do I update multiple context states?

**EDIT:**

Following *@Drew Reese*'s answer, this is my working Context file:

```
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
import { useState, createContext } from 'react';

const AppContext = createContext({
    email:'',
    isLoggedIn: false,
    userID: '',
    setEmail: () => {},
    setIsLoggedIn: () => {},
    setUserID: () => {},
});

const AppContextProvider = (props) => {
    const [ email, setEmail ] = useState(Cookies.get('email') || null);
    const [ userID, setUserID ] = useState(Cookies.get('uid') || null);
    const [ isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn ] = useState(Cookies.get('isLoggedIn') ? true : false);

    return (
        <AppContext.Provider value={{ email, setEmail, isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn, userID, setUserID }}>
            {props.children}
        </AppContext.Provider>
    );
}

export { AppContext, AppContextProvider };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your default context value should match what consumers expect.

[Updating Context from a Nested Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#updating-context-from-a-nested-component)

> It is often necessary to update the context from a component that is
> nested somewhere deeply in the component tree. In this case you can
> pass a function down through the context to allow consumers to update
> the context:
>
> ```
> // Make sure the shape of the default value passed to
> // createContext matches the shape that the consumers expect!
> export const ThemeContext = React.createContext({
>   theme: themes.dark,
>   toggleTheme: () => {},
> });
> ```

Update your `AppContext` default value to match what consumers will be using.

```
const AppContext = createContext([
  false,    // isLoggedIn
  () => {}, // setIsLoggedIn
  '',       // userID
  () => {}, // setUserID
  '',       // email
  () => {}, // setEmail
]);
```

Using an array like this may be a little cumbersome, consumers would need to keep the array indices straight when using destructuring assignment. Using an object instead makes consuming the context value a little more wieldy, now the order is irrelevant.

```
const AppContext = createContext({
  email: '',
  isLoggedIn: false,
  userID: '',
  setEmail: () => {},
  setIsLoggedIn: () => {},
  setUserID: () => {},
});
```

Usage:

```
const {
  isLoggedIn,
  setIsLoggedIn,
  userID,
  setUserID,
  email,
  setEmail,
} = useContext(AppContext);
```

> I could not get the context values in other components. How do I
> update multiple context states?

You should ensure that all consumers that you want to be able to update the context value are *actually* nested in the same `AppContextProvider` component.

Comment: How do I pass these `AppContext` object down through my `AppContextProvider()` wrapper function?

Comment: @forest You pass the context value the same way it was previously, `value={[isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn, userID, setUserID, email, setEmail]}` or as an object if you take my suggestion, `value={{ isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn, userID, setUserID, email, setEmail }}`.

Comment: @forest What is `userEmail`? It's not defined anywhere in your code snippet. Is this *something* your server is expecting in the POST request data, like `const data = { "userEmail": email, "password": password };`?

Comment: Well, actually I missed defining that as `useState()` inside the `AppContextProvider()` function. Now it's working. Updating my answer. Thanks!